# How can I suppress java compiler warnings about Sun proprietary API

Tags: java, eclipse, api, base64, sun

I'm using the encode() method from the sun.misc.BASE64Encoder package. How do I suppress the compiler warnings that it generates?

> sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in

And as a followup, why don't I see this warning in Eclipse?

Comment: Could replace it with another implementation, e.g., http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

Comment: Or http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: Rather than suppress the warning, why not [use the Java 8 supplied encoder rather than the proprietary API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could switch to a different Base64 implementation, e.g., http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html which is part of the Apache commons packages, which you might already have included in your classpath, or http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ which you could just take the implementation and stick in your source tree if you don't want another Jar on the path.

Comment: Can i just change the import to the Apache Commons version and evertyhing will work the same?

Answer (score 25):

There is a totally undocumented way to suppress the sun proprietary API warnings!
Add `-XDignore.symbol.file` to the `javac` command line.

I found this at https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476630 (scroll all the way to the very last comment). We all need to think kind thoughts about "xfournet" who added that last comment!

Comment: It's worth remembering why the warning exists, and why it's not supposed to be possible to shut it up, not with `@SuppressWarnings("all")`, or `-nowarn` or `-Xlint:none` or `-Xmaxwarns 0`. If you depend on internal classes your program will break sooner or later. But this is a neat hack when you know what you're doing and the proprietary API warning is just noise clogging the console. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[because you cannot disable this warning](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6476630)

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse does have a setting which (should) pick this up, see e.g. the desciption in [the Eclipse 3.1 release notes](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.1-200506271435/eclipse-news-part2.html):

Preferences → Java → Compiler → Errors/Warnings → Deprecated And Restricted API → Forbidden/Discouraged Reference

(and the project properties page to allow project-specific overrides of this setting)

Answer (score 2):

You can't switch them off, Eclipse simply filters them for you (if told to do so).

Quick interim fix on Linux:

```
javac *.java 2>&1 | pcregrep -v -M ".*Sun proprietary API.*\n.*\n.*\^"
```

2>&1  ... puts STDERR into STDOUT, so the pipeline "|" will  work

pcregrep might or might not be present on your system - if not, use your package utility (e.g. on Debian, Ubuntu etc: "sudo apt-get install pcregrep")

The expression searches for the "Sun proprietary API" warning and the following two lines (containing the line and the "^" indicating the position of the error in the line).

I leave the "XY warnings." line in at the end, lest I forget there *were* warnings ;o)
Note that if you have other warnings as well, the number reported there will of course not be correct :o)

NOTE also that standard "grep" does not work as well, because it can't span multiple lines.

Comment: ah but you can switch them off! see Michael Chaves answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you understand the inherent problems with using a proprietary API and decide to do it anyway, and if you are using maven, you might be interested in adding the following to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jdk 1.8 then you can use the below

```
java.util.Base64
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the call in a class which you place in a library jar on your classpath.  Then the warning only shows when that library is recompiled.

Answer (score -3):

The `javac` option `-Xlint:unchecked` does do the trick: it disables the warnings, see [the javac manual](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html) for details

Comment: Nope, that flag doesn't disable this particular warning.