# Adding a JfreeChart to SVG Image

Tags: java, svg, jfreechart, batik

I have a SVG image (a Map of a country) and I am trying to add a JfreeChart on top of it which would show 3d Bars on particular locations. Can someone please help point out how do i add a JfreeChart to an existing SVG image.

Following is the code so far

```
            String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
            SAXSVGDocumentFactory sax = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
            String uri = "file:///F://WorldMap.svg"; 
            SVGDocument doc = sax.createSVGDocument(uri); 
            SVGGraphics2D my_svg_generator = new SVGGraphics2D(doc);

            // Create a converter for this document.
            SVGGraphics2D g = new SVGGraphics2D(doc);

            //got a JfreeChart from a static method depending on data
            JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
            //I can add up normal nodes
            Element svgRoot = doc.getDocumentElement();
            svgRoot.appendChild(doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect"));
```

I have tried converting Jfreechart to Bytes and using g.drawBytes() but it renders some garbage on top of the SVG.

Would appreciate if someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

A jfreechart is an image so you need to create an image element and then turn the jfreechart data into a data uri and set the data url as the xlink:href attribute of the image.

jfreechart can generate gif, png or jpeg images so you'll have to adjust the [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) appropriately but it should look like this for a png image.

```
<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

Don't forget to convert the byte data to base64 too. There are various [base64 encoders around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)