# Convert double to file as a String/Chars (For encryption)

Tags: java

I'm trying to represent numbers to a String and backwards.
For instance if i have the number 64568899.
I want to represent it in a way i could decrypt it later but i 
need to write it as String or chars but not as a number.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you looking to **encrypt** it or **encode** it?

Comment: A string can contain numbers? Also numbers are legal char's. Do you have some special reason to convert numerical characters to [a-z]?

Comment: I'm looking for encryption but i want to be able to decrypt it later

Answer (score 0):

You can represent any binary data to string using base64 string. 
[Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

With doubles you might just need String.valueOf(double).

Comment: But i want to write it as chars not as an integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to convert your number into a String, just use the [valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method of `String` class:

```
String val = String.valueOf(number);
```

For converting Strings to Numbers use the `valueOf` methods of `Integer`, `Double` or `Float` (depends on which numbers you will have):

```
Integer val = Integer.valueOf(stringValue);
```