# Capture image from IP Camera with Java

Tags: java, base64, ip-camera

I want to capture image from IP Camera with Java. The IP-Camera is protected with user and password. The examples I've found are using the library from sun.*, but I would rather not use this in my code. Looking at the sourcecode of [this program](http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/defaul...e/2007/09/13/Viewing-and-storing-images-from-an-IP-Camera) ([IP-Camera image storing](http://blog.marcnuri.com/blog/defaul...e/2007/09/13/Viewing-and-storing-images-from-an-IP-Camera)), it uses an encoder from the `sun.*` packages, which I would rather not use in my code:

My problem is with this line:

```
String encoding = new Base64Encoder(userPassword).processString();
```

Does anybody have a suggestion as to how I can do this without using this package?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking directly for code, rather than helps with the steps towards solving the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java

Comment: Thanks HectorLector! That solved the problem