# How to conver (cast) double[] to byte[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, binary, type-conversion, base64

I want to encode `double[]` with `Base64` or similar. For this I need to have `byte[]` how to convert/represent/cast double array to byte array with minimal copying?

I was considering to use `ByteBuffer` and `DoubleBuffer` but this will require copying.

Comment: There is no way to do that without copying.

Comment: If you have not done so already see if any answers to [base64 encoding in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java) give you any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Base64OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) and write the bytes for your doubles out as you iterate over the array.