# How to convert a String-represented ByteBuffer into a byte array in Java

Tags: java, scala

I'm new to Java and I'm no sure how to do the following:

A Scala application somewhere converts a String into bytes:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes)
```

I collect this byte array as a Java `String`, and I wish to do the inverse of what the Scala code above did, hence get the original String (object `str` above).

Getting the `ByteBuffer` as a `String` to begin with is the only option I have, as I'm reading it from an AWS Kinesis stream (or is it?). The Scala code shouldn't change either.

Example string:

```
String str = "AAAAAAAAAAGZ7dFR0XmV23BRuufU+eCekJe6TGGUBBu5WSLIse4ERy9............";
```

How can this be achieved in Java?

**EDIT**

Okay, so I'll try to elaborate a little more about the process:

1. A 3rd party Scala application produces CSV rows which I need to consume
2. Before storing those rows in an AWS Kinesis stream, the application does the following to each row:

   ```
   ByteBuffer.wrap(output.getBytes);
   ```
3. I read the data from the stream as a string, and the string could look like the following one:

   ```
   String str = "AAAAAAAAAAGZ7dFR0XmV23BRuufU+eCekJe6TGGUBBu5WSLIse4ERy9............";
   ```
4. I need to restore the contents of the string above into its original, readable, form;

I hope I've made it clearer now, sorry for puzzling you all to begin with.

Comment: Won't something like `str.toCharArray.map(_.toByte)` work in Java?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure I unserstand what you did there with the `map(_.toByte)` part

Comment: "I read the data from the stream as a string" -- how?  Do you just pass the byte array into a `String` constructor, or do you use some kind of encoding like base64?

Comment: I googled aws kinesis and it seems like they base64 encode the records. Updated my answer.

Comment: Another lesson learnt from this: `GetShardIteratorResult.getShardIterator()` returns a string onle, while `GetRecordsRequest getRecordsRequest = new GetRecordsRequest();` along with `getRecords(getRecordsRequest);` gets the desired ByteBuffer type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go from `byte[]` to `String`, try `new String(yourBytes)`.

Both `getBytes` and the `String(byte[])` uses the default character encoding.

---

From [Amazon Kinesis Service API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html):

> *The data blob to put into the record, which is Base64-encoded when the blob is serialized.*

You need to base64 decode the string. Using Java 8 it would look like:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("AAAAAAAAAAGZ7dFR0XmV23BR........");
str = new String(bytes, "utf-8"));
```

Other options: [Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

Comment: I actually tried that, this could have been simpler if my input wasn't a String that is bytes (see above). What you suggest simply treats the string as if it was the content of it in its readable form.

Comment: Could you elaborate. I thought you basically wanted the inverse of getBytes?

Comment: Sure: I have a string that looks like this:
`"String str = "AAAAAAAAAAGZ7dFR0XmV23BR"`. I know that it's been converted to bytes but I get it as a String type. I want to know what's behind those bytes in a readable form

Comment: But how was `"AAAAAAAAAAGZ7dFR0XmV23BR"` produced? You mention getBytes, but that gives byte[] not String.

Comment: My apologies, my question was unorganized. what happens is this: 1. A Scala application takes a String, does `"getBytes()"`, wraps it in `ByteBuffer`. ---> 2. I read this ByteBuffer as a String. ---> I'd like to know what was originally the content of the string. In one code line, this is what's done with the original string: `ByteBuffer.wrap(output.getBytes)`

Comment: I'm having a hard time following.  Any chance you could amend your question with a step-by-step example that shows the string/byte data at each stage, and what result you are ultimately expecting?

Comment: Yes, you're both right, I'll edit the question and will elaborate the steps.

Comment: @aioobe, that worked just perfect. I had to problems: (1) Unfamiliarity with Java; (2) Unfamiliarity with AWS Java SDK; Combining your solution with changing the AWS method to fetch data from strings, so that instead of a String representation of the data, I would retrieve the original, ByteBuffer representation. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure if I understand the question exactly but do you mean this?

```
String decoded = new String(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String decoded = new String(bytesData);
    String actualString;
    try{
       actualString = new String(bytesData,"UTF-8");
       System.out.printLn("String is" + actualString);
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
       e.printstacktrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you suggest simply treats the string as if it were the content of it in its readable form. The original String looks like this:
`String str = "AAAAAAAAAAGZ7dFR0XmV23BR........"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,wrong answer. 
Again,ByteBuffer is a java class. SO they may work the same way
You need java version..

From kafka ApiUtils:

```
def writeShortString(buffer:ByteBuffer,string:String){
   if(String == null){
       buffer.putShort(-1)
   }
   else{
     val encodedString = string.getBytes(“utf-8”)
     if(encodedString.length > Short.MaxValue){
         throw YourException(Your Message)
     else{
        buffer.putShort(encodedString.length.asInstanceOf[Short])
        buffer.put(encodedString)
   }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For Kinesis data blobs:

```
private CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
decoder.decode(record.getData()).toString();
```