# download pdf file from url using silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, pdf, itext

I have pdf file in one URL , and what i'm looking for is to create one button in **silverlight** when I click it downloads this PDF file

The PDF's url download this file (if we use Browser) witch is generated in ASP.net and here the code  :

```
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Welcome to dotnetfox"));

        iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(new Uri(url));
        pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +
                                       "filename=demo.pdf");
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.Clear();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the `MemoryStream`, then you are getting the 0 bytes of this empty memory stream and sending them to the response, you are also just throwing away all the PDF stuff you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a similar mistake as the person who posted this question: [How to convert a pdf generating in response.outputStream to a Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457150/how-to-convert-a-pdf-generating-in-response-outputstream-to-a-base64-endoding)

You first tell iTextSharp to write PDF syntax straight to the `Outputstream` of the `Response`:

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
```

This `Outputstream` is **automatically closed** in this line:

```
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Everything that follows this `Close` line happens too late:

- You can not set headers *after* content has been written to the `Response.OutputStream`.
- You can no add extra content *after* the `Response.OutputStream` has been closed.

Moreover, you are converting an object `ms` to a byte array, but we don't see you adding any bytes to this `MemoryStream` anywhere.

Finally, the question is badly phrased.

- When you say *I have PDF file in one URL*, people will assume that you have a static PDF on a file system that can be reached using an URL. Your code sample contradicts this. In your code sample, you create a PDF on the fly in a web application. This is not the same as *having a PDF in one URL.*
- You say that you want a button in Silverlight that downloads the PDF when somebody clicks it, but I can't see any code that provides this button anywhere. My guess is that this part of your question is irrelevant. You want to create a PDF in a web application. It probably doesn't matter to you if you get this PDF from the application server using a browser or a button in Silverlight. If this assumption is wrong, then you are providing the wrong code sample. It is wrong because **it can never work** (for the reasons explained in my answer) and it is wrong because it is irrelevant if the actual problem is the button, not the PDF. If you want to get a document from an URL in Silverlight, then you shouldn't tag your question as a PDF or an iTextSharp question. Instead you should focus on the essence of your question: *How to create a button to fetch a document from a server?*