# How to convert utf-8 into base64 string?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have a base64 String and I have a function that actually encode Strings with "utf-8" like this :

```
public void send(Car charact,String data) {


    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "data " + URLEncoder.encode(data, "utf-8"));

        charact.setValue(URLEncoder.encode(data, "utf-8"));

   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So when I actually try send(myBase64String) , I have some characters that are replaced by %2F, %2B just as here http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php. 
I looked but didn't find a way to convert it into base64String. Can you advice please ? Thanks

Comment: Is `data` the Base64 encoded stirng?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode Base64 data in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Comment: Sorry, closed with the wrong question. This is right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java

Comment: So I don't see the problem. You have a base64 string which you URL encode. What's the problem?

Comment: We agree that it's encoding but at the end I have characters like %F, %2B etc which I don't want. I want that when i use the send() function, it actually sends the same Base64String

Comment: Then don't URL encode it. Do you know what URL encoding _is_?

Comment: Can you provide an expected input and output, this might clear up the confusion...

Comment: Well for an other reason I'm forced to use urlencoding (it's sending the datas to an embedded system). Let's say I do send(characterictic,Base64String), I'm getting the Base64String like I sent it but with those characters that I told you I don't want. I have to convert it before sending it or do something but I don't know what .. And if I don't use URLEncoder , i'm sending nothing to my embedded system however I can see in my log that It's working

Comment: Listen, if you are creating a URL, you need to URL encode the content in that URL. The receiving side of the URL can then decode it and receive your original content, which is the base64 string.