# Java Special Characters in Base64 encode

Tags: java, character-encoding, base64

I'm trying to use a basic64 encoding in my Java program.

The problem is that when I use

```
new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode("my string".getBytes())
```

I receive the base 64 string with \n and \r. I don't know how avoid this because when I write that string in a text File I get the following

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
yyyy
```

where the next line is produced by \n and \r.

I tried using a replace("\n","\n") and the same for \r but I want to know if there is a better solution or an extra parameter that I could use in Base64 encoding (or even other tipe of encoding.)

I changed the library and it is working!

here is the difference

Apache
Q0FTSCNTVUJJUiMzNWYwMjFiMC1kZWRjLTRmZjgtYjNjMS0wZDY0NmVkMjFmOGUjMjAzMzU1MzczMzY=

Sun
FWmsMAID7Ecbf8gUd0WIvKBjJNXhtMCbcKVDW0R4KXY/e1Do8lItqDN4NH/RiBdckoIMeFrncJ5X
Fju7R0cX822I/lFSkLab

Weird... I thought that Base64 was a standard...

Comment: Please avoid using `.getBytes()` method without an explicit charset. You risk data mangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why Developers Should Not Write Programs 
That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

> The sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface.  A
>   Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed
>   to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is
>   not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform.

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java):

> probably somthing like this:
>
> import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

Comment: But if I change the library the problem will be resolved? I mean, I will not have anymore \n and \r in my encoded String?

Comment: I think it will be resolved, since sun library is chunking the output, hence the carriage return symbol that is not a part of the base64 table.

Comment: yep, It worked, here is the difference

Q0FTSCNTVUJJUiMzNWYwMjFiMC1kZWRjLTRmZjgtYjNjMS0wZDY0NmVkMjFmOGUjMjAzMzU1MzczMzY=
[VS]
FWmsMAID7Ecbf8gUd0WIvKBjJNXhtMCbcKVDW0R4KXY/e1Do8lItqDN4NH/RiBdckoIMeFrncJ5X
Fju7R0cX822I/lFSkLab