# How to pass a file path via Url to web server?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jersey

I am developing a web service using jersey and Maven. I want to pass a file path via Url to send the it to server. But i got an error as:
[image]

in web server:

```
@Path("/hello") //Path
public class HelloWorldService {
@GET
    @Path("/{param}") //parameter
    public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException, FileFormatException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        String output ="Server response: "+  msg; //Get the file path here.
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }
}
```

How to i can pass the path to server?

Comment: need to encode the URL param. If you are using javascript to send the request then take a look at `encodeURI()`

Answer (score 2):

Check the following  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java) then...

**...encode** path with [base 64](https://www.base64encode.org/) on the client side and **decode** it on the server

Let's say You have 'C:\path\to\your\file.jar' path

Encode it with base 64: **QzpccGF0aFx0b1x5b3VyXGZpbGUuamFy**

Then send the following request to the server:

localhost:8080/files/**QzpccGF0aFx0b1x5b3VyXGZpbGUuamFy**

Answer (score 0):

you should not be passing the file path as an request parameter , because it will not parse properly / character. On click on "send to server button" you can repalce / by some other character like # and at server side you can parse again.