# Is Java 8 java.util.Base64 a drop-in replacement for sun.misc.BASE64?

Tags: java, encoding, java-8, base64, mime

***Question***

Are the Java 8 `java.util.Base64` MIME Encoder and Decoder ***a drop-in replacement*** for the unsupported, internal Java API `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` and `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`?

<sub>EDIT (Clarification): By ***drop-in replacement***
I mean that I can switch legacy code using `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` and `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` to Java 8 MIME Base64 Encoder/Decoder for any existing other client code transparently.</sub>

***What I think so far and why***

Based on my investigation and quick tests (see code below) ***it should be a drop-in replacement*** because

- `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` based on its JavaDoc is *a BASE64 Character encoder as specified in **RFC1521**. This RFC is part of the **MIME** specification...*
- `java.util.Base64` based on its [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) *Uses the "The Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 1 of **RFC 2045** for encoding and decoding operation...* under **MIME**

Assuming no significant changes in the RFC 1521 and 2045 (I could not find any) and based on my quick test using the Java 8 Base64 MIME Encoder/Decoder should be fine.

***What I am looking for***

- an authoritative source confirming or disproving the "drop-in replacement" point OR
- a counterexample which shows a case where java.util.Base64 has different behaviour than the sun.misc.BASE64Encoder [OpenJDK Java 8 implementation (8u40-b25)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/misc/BASE64Encoder.java/) (BASE64Decoder) OR
- whatever you think answers above question *definitely*

***For reference***

My test code

```
public class Base64EncodingDecodingRoundTripTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String test1 = " ~!@#$%^& *()_+=`| }{[]\\;: \"?><,./ ";
        String test2 = test1 + test1;

        encodeDecode(test1);
        encodeDecode(test2);
    }

    static void encodeDecode(final String testInputString) throws IOException {
        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder unsupportedEncoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        sun.misc.BASE64Decoder unsupportedDecoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();

        Base64.Encoder mimeEncoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder();
        Base64.Decoder mimeDecoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder();

        String sunEncoded = unsupportedEncoder.encode(testInputString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("sun.misc encoded: " + sunEncoded);

        String mimeEncoded = mimeEncoder.encodeToString(testInputString.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Java 8 Base64 MIME encoded: " + mimeEncoded);

        byte[] mimeDecoded = mimeDecoder.decode(sunEncoded);
        String mimeDecodedString = new String(mimeDecoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        byte[] sunDecoded = unsupportedDecoder.decodeBuffer(mimeEncoded); // throws IOException
        String sunDecodedString = new String(sunDecoded, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println(String.format("sun.misc decoded: %s | Java 8 Base64 decoded:  %s", sunDecodedString, mimeDecodedString));

        System.out.println("Decoded results are both equal: " + Objects.equals(sunDecodedString, mimeDecodedString));
        System.out.println("Mime decoded result is equal to test input string: " + Objects.equals(testInputString, mimeDecodedString));
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by drop-in replacement? Are you just talking about the encoding/decoding behavior?

Comment: @Cubic: I mean by drop-in replacement that I can switch legacy code using  sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder to Java 8 MIME Base64 Encoder/Decoder for any existing other client code transparently. This seems to be the case, but I like to have an authoritative reference confirming this or a "proof" that this is not the case, otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you can switch the legacy code to the new Java 8 Base64 Encoder/Decoder. They will always produce the same output.

Comment: Relevant for asking [*which* encoder class to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)?

Comment: @Raedwald I don't think so. This question and answer documents the problem when legacy code uses the unofficial Java internal APIs (supposedly-never-to-be-used-by-anyone) `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` and `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`. This question/answer is about migrating such legacy code to the official Java 8 Base64 APIs.
The [answer to which encoder class to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109632/5698098) already suggests to use the Java 8 Base64 APIs and doesn't point you to those legacy `sun.misc` APIs.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here's a small test program that illustrates a difference in the encoded strings:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[57];
String enc1 = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
String enc2 = new String(java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode(bytes),
                         StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

System.out.println("enc1 = <" + enc1 + ">");
System.out.println("enc2 = <" + enc2 + ">");
System.out.println(enc1.equals(enc2));
```

Its output is:

```
enc1 = <AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
enc2 = <AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA>
false
```

Note that the encoded output of `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` has a newline at the end. It doesn't *always* append a newline, but it happens to do so if the encoded string has exactly 76 characters on its last line. (The author of `java.util.Base64` considered this to be a small bug in the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` implementation – see the [review thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-October/011737.html)).

This might seem like a triviality, but if you had a program that relied on this specific behavior, switching encoders might result in malformed output. Therefore, I conclude that `java.util.Base64` is **not** a drop-in replacement for `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`.

Of course, the *intent* of `java.util.Base64` is that it's a functionally equivalent, RFC-conformant, high-performance, fully supported and specified replacement that's intended to support migration of code away from `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`. You need to be aware of some edge cases like this when migrating, though.

Comment: _Perfect_, you found a counterexample!

Comment: Indeed, it would have been really nice if this and any other corner cases  (if they exist) were documented properly. Do you know of any other edge cases?

Comment: @IvoMori I'm not aware of any other edge cases, though there probably are some. I doubt they'll be documented. The problem, and this applies to the `sun.misc` stuff in general, is that it was never formally specified, and there is no suite of conformance and regression tests like there is for the `java.*` APIs. The `sun.misc.BASE64` stuff is just a lump of code that "did what it did" and so it's quite possible or even likely that there are odd edge case behaviors or even bugs lurking there.

Comment: in android problem occers... `Call requires API level 26 (current min is 21): java.util.Base64#getMimeEncoder more... (Ctrl+F1)`

Comment: My own observation is that sun.misc.BASE64Encoder inserts a newline after *every* 76 characters, not just the specific case of the encoded string being exactly 76 characters in length. I discovered this while troubleshooting an incompatibility with the PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey() function in the OpenSSL library, which is expecting those newlines to be included.

Comment: for me I had an issue with a newline at the start of the String before decoding. The `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` happily removed newline characters before decoding, the `java.util.Base64.Decoder` threw an `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue, when i moved from `sun` to `java.util.base64`, but then `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` solved my problem

Comment: This comment should be made more visible as org.apache.commons.codec.binary is more versatile than the java.util library

Comment: I'm sorry, but **I fail to see how your answer gives an answer to my question**. I asked specifically whether the official Java 8 Base64 API can be used as a drop-in replacement (no change in any behaviour) for legacy code which uses the `sun.misc` Base64 API. [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384409/5698098) gave already the final answer by showing a counter example that this isn't the case. Your late answer should/can be the answer for a different question. Instead **your late answer** simply seems to "hijack" my question to promote the use of a third-party library.

Comment: Did you actually verify that the ``org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`` API is a drop-in replacement for the ``sun.misc`` API? According to you any ``sun.misc`` Base64 encoding can be reproduced using the ``org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`` API – right? As people are interested in the Apache Commons Codec library, I'll follow up with a new question which is specific to that third-party library.

Comment: To follow up on your off-topic answer, I created a separate question: [Is Apache Commons Codec Base64 a drop-in replacement for sun.misc.BASE64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61863542/5698098). **Also note that I wasn't able to confirm your answer here to be correct.** Please provide your proof or code example for your claim by answering conclusively [Is Apache Commons Codec Base64 a drop-in replacement for sun.misc.BASE64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61863542/5698098).

Comment: `Base64.encodeBase64String(passwdstring.getBytes())` replaced my `new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(passwdstring.getBytes())` with success

Answer (score 4):

There are no changes to the base64 specification between rfc1521 and rfc2045.

All base64 implementations could be considered to be drop-in replacements of one another, the only differences between base64 implementations are:

1. the alphabet used.
2. the API's provided (e.g. some might take only act on a full input buffer, while others might be finite state machines allowing you to continue to push chunks of input through them until you are done).

The MIME base64 alphabet has remained constant between RFC versions (it *has* to or older software would break) and is: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+/`

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) notes, only the last 2 characters may change between base64 implementations.

As an example of a base64 implementation that *does* change the last 2 characters, the [IMAP MUTF-7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.1.3) specification uses the following base64 alphabet: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz+,`

The reason for the change is that the `/` character is often used as a path delimiter and since the MUTF-7 encoding is used to flatten non-ASCII directory paths into ASCII, the `/` character needed to be avoided in encoded segments.

Comment: Up-voting your explanation as it makes perfectly sense and it also corresponds with what I figured out from the start. Still hoping for some "official" reference - _if it even exists_. I'd expect that the [Java 8 Adaption Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk8-adoption-guide-2157601.html) or the [JEP 135](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/135) would clearly state that the Java 8 Base64 Encoder/Decoder replace the internal `sun.misc.BASE64` implementations. But well, maybe it's just too obvious... Anyway, this QA format becomes then that "official" reference.

Comment: It seems that sun.* namespaces should not be used: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html which suggests that the java.util.* base64 classes were added to appease developers who needed base64 support and were having to either implement their own classes or use [3rd party solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java).

Comment: You could also take, as official proof, that [rfc2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt) specifically states that it obsoletes rfc1521.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both encoders are bug free, then the RFC requires distinct encodings for every 0 byte, 1 byte, 2 byte and 3 bytes sequence. Longer sequences are broken down into as many 3 byte sequences as needed followed by a final sequence. Hence if the two implementations handle all 16,843,009 (1+256+65536+16777216) possible sequences correctly, then the two implementations are also identical.

These tests only take a few minutes to run. By slightly changing your test code, I have done that and my Java 8 installation passed all the test. Hence the public implementation can be used to safely replace the sun.misc implementation.

Here is my test code:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Base64EncodingDecodingRoundTripTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Testing zero byte encoding");
        encodeDecode(new byte[0]);

        System.out.println("Testing single byte encodings");
        byte[] test = new byte[1];
        for(int i=0;i<256;i++) {
            test[0] = (byte) i;
            encodeDecode(test);
        }
        System.out.println("Testing double byte encodings");
        test = new byte[2];
        for(int i=0;i<65536;i++) {
            test[0] = (byte) i;
            test[1] = (byte) (i >>> 8);
            encodeDecode(test);
        }
        System.out.println("Testing triple byte encodings");
        test = new byte[3];
        for(int i=0;i<16777216;i++) {
            test[0] = (byte) i;
            test[1] = (byte) (i >>> 8);
            test[2] = (byte) (i >>> 16);
            encodeDecode(test);
        }
        System.out.println("All tests passed");
    }

    static void encodeDecode(final byte[] testInput) throws IOException {
        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder unsupportedEncoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        sun.misc.BASE64Decoder unsupportedDecoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();

        Base64.Encoder mimeEncoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder();
        Base64.Decoder mimeDecoder = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder();

        String sunEncoded = unsupportedEncoder.encode(testInput);
        String mimeEncoded = mimeEncoder.encodeToString(testInput);

        // check encodings equal
        if( ! sunEncoded.equals(mimeEncoded) ) {
            throw new IOException("Input "+Arrays.toString(testInput)+" produced different encodings (sun=\""+sunEncoded+"\", mime=\""+mimeEncoded+"\")");
        }

        // Check cross decodes are equal. Note encoded forms are identical
        byte[] mimeDecoded = mimeDecoder.decode(sunEncoded);
        byte[] sunDecoded = unsupportedDecoder.decodeBuffer(mimeEncoded); // throws IOException
        if(! Arrays.equals(mimeDecoded,sunDecoded) ) {
            throw new IOException("Input "+Arrays.toString(testInput)+" was encoded as \""+sunEncoded+"\", but decoded as sun="+Arrays.toString(sunDecoded)+" and mime="+Arrays.toString(mimeDecoded));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach. However, Stuart's answer includes a counterexample which shows an edge case where the two resulting encodings are not identical.

Answer (score 1):

Stuart Marks' answer is almost correct. The getMimeEncoder in his example above should be configured like this to emulate sun.misc:

```
String enc2 = new String(java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder(76, new byte[]{0xa}).encode(bytes),
                     StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

At this point, it will be a drop-in as requested in the original post.