# Is Apache Commons Codec Base64 a drop-in replacement for sun.misc.BASE64?

Tags: java, base64, encoder

***Background***

This is a follow-up question to my original question [Migrating from sun.misc.BASE64 to Java 8 java.util.Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301409/5698098) because [someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55685147/5698098) that the Apache Commons Codec Base64 API is a drop-in replacement to migrate code which uses the `sun.misc` Base64 APIs.

***Question***

Is the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` ***a drop-in replacement*** for the unsupported, internal Java API `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` and `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`?

***Drop-in replacement*** means that the encoding/decoding results from both implementations (Apache Commons Codec and `sun.misc`) are equal, thus the they can be used interchangebly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stuart Marks perfect counter-example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384409/5698098) to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301409/5698098) shows definitely  that for at least one edge case the Java 8 `java.util.Base64` MIME Encoder delivers a different result than the unsupported, internal Java API `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`.

So let's check that edge case again using the [Apache Commons Codec library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/index.html).

***Edge-case test***

For the following test I use the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` implementation of OpenJDK 7 and Apache Commons Codec library 1.14.

```
public class StuartMarksBase64EncodingEdgeCaseTestForApacheCommonsCodec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[57];
        String enc1 = new sun_misc_jdk7.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
        String enc2 = new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

        System.out.println("enc1 = <" + enc1 + ">");
        System.out.println("enc2 = <" + enc2 + ">");
        System.out.println(enc1.equals(enc2));
    }

}
```

This then results in the output

```
enc1 = <AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>
enc2 = <AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA>
false
```

***Conclusion***

Given the test output I conclude that the Apache Commons Codec Base64 API is ***not a drop-in replacement*** to migrate code which uses the `sun.misc` Base64 APIs.