# The import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder cannot be resolved when the project is imported into Eclipse

Tags: java, base64

I have this old project which was implemented a long time ago, and it uses sun.misc.BASE64Decoder and sun.misc.BASE64Encoder. When I imported the project into Eclipse it is showing me the that their imports cannot be resolved to a valid object.

I have tried using all the recommended methods on Stack overflow like turning errors into warnings. For references here's a screenshot

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: That package removed in Java 9. If it is possible strongly recommended to change those classes to an other e.g. some of ```java.util.*``` or use an ancient Java. Here is a link to migration: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using JDK 8+ then the reason is likely that the package for Base64Encoder and Base64Decoder has changed from sun.misc to java.util (see [Is Java 8 java.util.Base64 a drop-in replacement for sun.misc.BASE64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301409/is-java-8-java-util-base64-a-drop-in-replacement-for-sun-misc-base64))

You could either use an older JDK or replace the package.

Normally you don't have to expect the JDK packages to change - *except* for javax.* and sun.*.
As far as I know these packages were originally for vendor specific or experimental classes and IIRC the Java docs explicitly mention that this could change - although this rarely happens.

Comment: That helps a lot, let me try to downgrade to an older JDK

Answer (score 0):

Classes from the `sun` package are deprecated and have been removed in newer JDK versions. So your old project will likely not find them anymore.

You should migrate to the respective replacements from [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).