# Issue in generating session key

Tags: java, encryption, session-keys

I amusing following code to generate sessionkeu

```
  public byte[] generateSessionKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException 
          {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES","BC");
    kgen.init(256);
    SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] symmKey = key.getEncoded();
    return symmKey;
        }
```

and printing it here

```
  byte[] aa=encryptor.generateSessionKey();
  String s1=new String(aa);
  System.out.println(s1);
```

and output is

```
 ÇÉ¤Ä‘y3F:¦ïó‹AOÜYu•{Öç„>r?Ô–
```

am I doing it right ?

Comment: try doing round trip encryption / decryption

Comment: Yes, the output is "correct". What did you expect? What's the problem? Remember that bytes and printable characters are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [`new String(aa)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])) is highly likely to be incorrect. It's directly converting the `byte[]` into a string using the platform's default character set. This means it's potentially different for each platform this runs on.

Common ways of displaying, transmitting or storing `byte[]` as strings include [base16 (hexadecimal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) representation, and [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java).