# Similar Java function like atob in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, base64

I have Query parameter that was encoded by `btoa` javascript function. when url clicked, request function called inside java controller where i wanted to decode Query parameter (which is encoded from javascript btoa). i have tried `BASE64Decoder` and `Base64.getDecoder()` but not able to get proper value. is there any other way to do so?

**Java Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "decode/{email}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String decodeEmail(Model model, @PathVariable String email){
        Decode decode = new Decode();
        decode.setEmail(email);
        decodeService.save(decode);
        return "decode/List";
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var encodedEmail = btoa(email);
```

**Example**

String to encode : demo@demo.com

Encoded String : ZGVtb0BkZW1vLmNvbQ==

Comment: If you could post exact examples of the Javascript Base64 encoding of some sample strings we could confirm correctness.

Comment: i have updated my question with example

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Java 8 has a new [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) package:

```
public void test() {
    String s = "demo@demo.com";
    String encoded = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(s.getBytes()));
    String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded));
    System.out.println("S: " + s + " -> " + encoded + " -> " + decoded);
}
```

prints

```
S: demo@demo.com -> ZGVtb0BkZW1vLmNvbQ== -> demo@demo.com
```

There are also other encoder/decoder pairs - you may find the [mime encoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getMimeEncoder--) appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Why always **new String** is required ?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I tried String.valueOf() , it didn't work . Any reason ?

Comment: `String encoded = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(s.getBytes()));`

can be replaced with
`String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s.getBytes());`

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is here using apache library : [Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java?rq=1)

otherwise the implementation from wiki definition will do  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Sample_Implementation_in_Java