# Encryption program returning weird string for encryption but correct string after decryption

Tags: java, encryption, xor

I am performing xor encryption in Java. It encrypts a byte array, converts it into a String, and then prints the String.

However, when I execute it, I get strange "boxes" in the output (Eclipse console).

The algorithm code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < messageArr.length; i++)
{
    encryptedMessage[i] = (byte) (messageArr[i]^codebookArr[i]);
}

String eMessage = new String(encryptedMessage);
return eMessage;
```

The `main` method:

```
String lMessage = e.xorEncrypt(message, codebook);
System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + lMessage);
String uMessage = e.xorEncrypt(lMessage, codebook);
System.out.println("Unencrypted message: " + uMessage);
```

When I run this code, it prints strange "boxes" for the encrypted string. However, when it decrypts the string, I receive the original output, showing that the encryption algorithm works.

Why do I receive the strange boxes for the encrypted output, but the correct string when I decrypt it?

Comment: Can you provide the data of `message` and `codebook`?

Comment: You get boxes because they are not readable ascii characters

Comment: You're trying to transform arbitrary, binary bytes to a String, using the platform default encoding. You can't expect to get back only valid, printable characters. Not all byte sequences are valid character sequences in all encodings, and not all characters are printable.

Comment: Message when I just tested was "encrypt" and codebook was "thisiscode" again, intial encryption output was strange boxes but when that string with weird boxes was run back through with the codebook I got the right output as "encrypt".

Comment: Why do you expect something printable when you print the encrypted stuff?

Comment: Just assumed it could be printable, is there any way to make it printable as a string? Any object I could use? Not sure that it really matters if it decrypts it correctly but thinking out loud.

Comment: Sure. Use Base64 encoding to transform the arbitrary byte array into a sequence of printable characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Base64 encoding after encryption (it is a best practice) so you don't get weird boxes and no special characters get lost in "travel".

A good reference:

[Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

You will get a string somewhat like this:  b2xkIGNyb3cgbWVkaWNpbmUgc2hvdw==