# Passing image to controller class in JSON format in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax, image

Is it possible to store an image and some column fields in mysql database using only AJAX without `action` attribute in `form` tag?  I am using `contentType` as JSON in AJAX to pass my column fields.

Is there any solution to send the image in the JSON format. Kindly provide the solution.

Comment: You can look at [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), to store images as a text in DB or send them inside JSON (here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109632/8554766) addressing, how to do it in Java). Though, if you would share some more details of what exactly you are trying to accomplish and why - it is possible that you better off doing it in some other way.

Comment: It would also be nice, if you'd share some things you have tried already.

Comment: @Filipp                                                                                                   
 Thank you ,will upload the program contents and will share the link.

Comment: @Flipp   Please find the link for program written to store images using 
              mysql         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457975/image-storing-in-mysql-database-with-spring-mvc-and-hibernate-using-ajax