# Getting an error when trying to convert an element of a char array to int

Tags: java, arrays, numberformatexception

Below is the code I have used so far:

```
public static String encrypt(String password) {
    String encrypted = null;
    char passChars[] = password.toCharArray();
    int ascii[] = null;
    for(int i=0;i<passChars.length;i++) {
        ascii[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(passChars[i]));
        ascii[i] = ascii[i] + 17;
        passChars[i] = (char)ascii[i];
        encrypted = encrypted + String.valueOf(passChars[i]);
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

When I try to run this, it is getting run but when I use the encrypt method, I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "M"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.package.program.Encryptor.encrypt(Encrypter.java:46)
at com.package.program.Main$3.actionPerformed(Main.java:136)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried changing a few things, such as changing the way it char is being converted to int but nothing seemed to work... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "encrypt" the string by just offsetting each character by some amount, then just do that directly:

```
String encrypted = null;
char passChars[] = password.toCharArray();
for (int i=0; i < passChars.length; i++) {
    passChars[i] += 17;
}
encrypted = new String(passChars);
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that adding 17 to certain ASCII characters may land you on something which is not printable.  It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve here; if you want to systematically scramble a password into other characters, then we would have to wrap around using the modulus perhaps.

Comment: I want to encrypt a password so i can store it in a database. This is only a prototype though... Thank you

Comment: @MilanJ For a next step, you may consider base 64 encoding your password, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java).  Beyond that, we could discuss things like formal encryption using a salt.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
ascii[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(passChars[i]));
```

You're trying to convert the letters of your password, to integers. There is no guarantee that the password is composed of only numbers.

Instead, you can do:

```
ascii[i] = passChars[i] + 17;
```

directly.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize ascii[] with valid size other wise you may get index out of bound exception and this program will work only for password as a numeric string only.