# How to correctly encode and decode a string in Base64?

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode

I want to encode a string in Base64 for later decoding it. I encode it doing this:

```
public static String encryptString(String string) {     
    byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(string.getBytes());
    return (new String(bytesEncoded));
}
```

Then, the encoded string is stored on disk using UTF-8. After restarting the application, the encoded string is readed from disk and I'm trying to decode the string using this:

```
public static String decryptString(String string) {
    byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
    return (new String(valueDecoded));
}
```

Something is wrong because it is giving me this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character d
at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:743)
at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:535)
at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:558)
```

This is a TRACE step by step

1º i encode this: `{"configuration":{"shop":{"name":"","addressLine1":"","addressLine2":"","postalCode":"","city":"","country":"","phoneNumber":""}},"jointBets":[],"groups":[{"name":"Test","members":[]}]}`

into this: `eyJjb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIjp7InNob3AiOnsibmFtZSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3NMaW5lMSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3NMaW5lMiI6IiIsInBvc3RhbENvZGUiOiIiLCJjaXR5IjoiIiwiY291bnRyeSI6IiIsInBob25lTnVtYmVyIjoiIn19LCJqb2ludEJldHMiOltdLCJncm91cHMiOlt7Im5hbWUiOiJUZXN0IiwibWVtYmVycyI6W119XX0=`

2º i store it on disk in utf8

3º i retreive it from disk and it's this string:

```
eyJjb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIjp7InNob3AiOnsibmFtZSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3NMaW5lMSI6IiIsImFkZHJlc3NMaW5lMiI6IiIsInBvc3RhbENvZGUiOiIiLCJjaXR5IjoiIiwiY291bnRyeSI6IiIsInBob25lTnVtYmVyIjoiIn19LCJqb2ludEJldHMiOltdLCJncm91cHMiOlt7Im5hbWUiOiJUZXN0IiwibWVtYmVycyI6W119XX0=
```

4º i decode it and get the exception.

Comment: why don't you `encodeToString`? but tried your code (jshell) worked fine

Comment: I assume `.decode(string)` should be `.decode(string.getBytes())` as well.

Comment: maybe you could post the data that is generating that error (I wonder how d is an invalid Base64 character???) ((changing default charset between runs?)

Comment: `getBytes()` could be a problem because it uses your system's local default character set.  Which could be different on different systems.

Comment: or `new String(byte[])` that uses the system default charset while `decode` uses ISO8859-1 (despite this shouldn't have any influence on Base64 characters, or? UTF16LE/BE)

Comment: just tested with `new String(bytesEncoded, UTF_16)` and got similar exception when decoding.... don't happen if using `encodeToString` (uses ISO8859-1)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger same error using encodeToString

Comment: btw i'm storing the encoded string into disk using utf-8 before decoding it, later i'm reading it from disk. Maybe that's the problem? how to solve it?

Comment: check the strings (bytes) being written to and read from disk... > *"maybe you could post the data that is generating that error"*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov no, delete your possible duplicat erequests and read the coments

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i added the trace on the questions with the data

Comment: I checked the source of decode, `d` is the hexadecimal value (`Integer.toString(char, 16)`) of the offending character, in this case probably a carriage return which is outside the base64 alphabet and shouldn't be there - try the MIME encoders/decoders of Base64 (or avoid the carriage return/linefeeds)

Comment: can't understand how to do that.. please can you post a sample?

Comment: `Base64.getMimeEncoder()` `...getMimeDecoder()` (or/and change how writing/reading from disk)

Comment: sorry but can't understand what to do with that

Comment: omg it's working with that. What's the explanation about this? can you writte an answer with your solution and explaining why that solve the issue? i will accept it

Comment: instead of `Base64.getEncoder()` you write `Base64.getMimeEncoder()` - these ignore invalid characters: *"**MIME** ... All line separators or other characters not found in the base64 alphabet table are ignored in decoding operation"*

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger ignored? then they will be lost? in that case this is useless :S

Comment: the ignored characters are  NOT part of the encoded data - they are just *noise* - if this is a problem you should NOT write/read the extra carriage return (maybe you are using `println`??? but, after 8 years of SO you should know about [mcve] )

Comment: what do you mean? For example, i want to add this: "España" which contains a character that isn't in the base64 alphabet. What will happen with that character? will it be lost when encoded ? so after decoded should it be "Espaa" ?

Comment: you should first encode it, to obtain base64 (characters), that is "RXNwYfFh" for above string - somehow I have the impression that you do not know what Base64 is for

Comment: I can't understand you. Please, can you explain it with my sample?  i want to add this: "España" which contains a character that isn't in the base64 alphabet. What will happen with that character? will it be lost when encoded ? so after decoded should it be "Espaa" ?

Comment: "España" sure is not Base64, it must be encoded first - what **you** are doing with first part of **your** program - would result in "RXNwYfFh" - but if you now (for example, I must assume since we dont know it) use `println` it will have an additional linefeed added to the end (the `ln` part of the method) which is not allowed in plain base64

Comment: if then use the MIME decoder it will ignore the extra linefeed and still return "España" if  feed with "RXNwYfFh\n" - have you tried it to see if it is returning "Espaa"???

Comment: then, can the base64 decoded text be different from the original non encoded text in any situation?

Comment: WHY are you using Base64? it will not be different as long as it not changed between encoding and decoding

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger because i need to store the string in a non human readable condition, so, encrypted or encoded

Comment: then Base64 is not the indicated one...non-readable maybe, encrypt sure not. almost all *nix system have a command to encode/decode it It is just a method to encode **binary** data using ASCII character that can safely be transferred between system (e.g. in older days by E-Mail or forums).

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger this is a java application used in Windows OS, so i think can't have that easy function

Comment: not to hard in windows (powershell has it, if I am not wrong, I use it a lot in git-bash on windows) e.g. https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/04/26/base64-encode-or-decode-on-the-command-line-without-installing-extra-tools-on-linux-windows-or-macos/ or online https://www.base64encode.org/

Comment: I'm considering using google Tink library, but it seems that is too much complex for just encrypt and decrypt a string

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger please whould you post an answer with your solution of getMime... ? I'll mark as accepted

Answer (score 3):

The old Base64 utility add linebreaks every 76 characters in Java8. 
The result looks like that:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy
MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCABkAGQDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
...
```

It seems that this behaviour changed with some version. At least with Java11 the decoder is not accepting line-breaks anymore.
To avoid the problem you could change you method

```java
public static String decryptString(String string) {
    byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string.replace("\n","").replace("\r","");
    return new String(valueDecoded);
}
```

Comment: I used `base64 -w 0` and despite having no linebreaks I still got that error. Only changing Base64.getDecoder() to Base64.getMimeDecoder() helped, I don't really know why.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, the encoded string is stored on disk using UTF-8. After
>   restarting the application, the encoded string is readed from disk and
>   I'm trying to decode the string using this:

This seems to be a point of failure. Most likely your problem is OS/JDK dependent Apparently the following code seems to work well for me (Win 7, latest JDK 1.8):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String source = "{\"configuration\":{\"shop\":{\"name\":\"España\",\"addressLine1\":\"\",\"addressLine2\":\"\"," +
                "\"postalCode\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"phoneNumber\":\"\"}},\"jointBets\":[]," +
                "\"groups\":[{\"name\":\"Test\",\"members\":[]}]}";

    // Encode string
    String encoded = encryptString(source);

    System.out.println("Base64 encoded: " + encoded);

    // Temp Dir
    String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

    // Write to File
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempDir + "data.txt"))) {
        writer.write(encoded);
    }

    // Read from File
    Path path = Paths.get(tempDir + "data.txt");

    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
    String dataFromFile = lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    lines.close();

    // Compare content
    assert encoded.equals(dataFromFile);

    // Decode string
    String decoded = decryptString(dataFromFile);
    System.out.println("Base64 decoded: " + decoded);
}

public static String encryptString(String string) {
    byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return new String(bytesEncoded);
}

public static String decryptString(String string) {
    byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
    return new String(valueDecoded);
}
```

> Base64 encoded:
>   eyJjb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIjp7InNob3AiOnsibmFtZSI6IkVzcGHDsWEiLCJhZGRyZXNzTGluZTEiOiIiLCJhZGRyZXNzTGluZTIiOiIiLCJwb3N0YWxDb2RlIjoiIiwiY2l0eSI6IiIsImNvdW50cnkiOiIiLCJwaG9uZU51bWJlciI6IiJ9fSwiam9pbnRCZXRzIjpbXSwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoiVGVzdCIsIm1lbWJlcnMiOltdfV19
>
> Base64 decoded:
>   {"configuration":{"shop":{"name":"España","addressLine1":"","addressLine2":"","postalCode":"","city":"","country":"","phoneNumber":""}},"jointBets":[],"groups":[{"name":"Test","members":[]}]}

Comment: his problem is reading a carriage return (code `d`)  probably at the end of the text, that is not allowed in plain  base64

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not specifying a charset. Try running the below maybe with and without the charset specified for the `String` constructor to verify.

```
   @Test
    public void base64Test() throws Exception{
        String string = "ABCDF";

        byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(string.getBytes());
        String encodedStr = (new String(bytesEncoded,Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
        System.out.println(encodedStr);

        byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedStr);
        String decodedStr = (new String(valueDecoded,Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
        System.out.println(decodedStr);
    }
```

Comment: first part is exactly what `encodeToString` does (as commented/suggested/asked above)