# Byte Array to base64 conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pdf, base64

I'm fetching a pdf using API call which return it in byte array format.

I need to convert it to base64, so that the same can be shared over email as an attachment.

The API call returns something like this:
"%PDF-1.5 ... %EOF"

A direct base64 conversion results in an empty pdf file.

The code used:

```
var returnedValues = await requestPDF(url, "get", headersvalue, "");
base64data = Buffer.from(returnedValues,'binary').toString('base64')
var toReturn =  {"status": true,"data": base64data};
return toReturn;
```

When I pass the returned value to my third party mail service as an attachment, the resultant mail contains a pdf but a blank one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java

Comment: This question appears to be about JS. Why is there people flagging as duplicate of Java related questions ?

Comment: You should post more code, you might have an error before or after the conversion.

Comment: @TaaviKivimaa the difference between  Java and JavaScript is bigger that the difference between Car and Carpet.