# How to convert a byte string to String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, encoding, byte

I am calling a .NET service using Java, which is returning a string of data representing the bytes of a csv string. I've heavily truncated the response below to show the encoding format I receive it as:

```
77u/UHJvDQoNCg==
```

I now want to convert this data back to a csv string so I can see its original csv format. I have tried to convert it back to a byte[] and also encode with UTF-8 and UTF-16 but it just shows the string as above. How can I convert it back to a csv string?

Comment: This looks like base64 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java) but there's no way of knowing without an entire sample input string and more context. If it is, that SO page should help decode it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't recognize it was Base64. I essentially used the getdecoder() method to decode the string back to its original format.