# How to Create a JWT in Java with the secret base64 encoded

Tags: java, base64, jwt

Using the online JWT debugger  to encode and decode a JWT  token I created this simple token

https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.5T7L_L1MPfQ_5FjKGa1fTPqrzwK4bNSM812nW6oyjb8

The secret to encode the token is
`qwertypassword`

The header is `{ "alg": "HS256"}`

The payload is `{ "sub": "admin", "aud": "Solr"}`

When you encoded with the secret not base64 encoded, it generates the JWT
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.5T7L_L1MPfQ_5FjKGa1fTPqrzwK4bNSM812nW6oyjb8`

When the  secret is base64 encoded it generates the JWT
`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.SWCJDd6B_m7xr_puQH-wgbxvXyJYXH9lTpldOU0eQKc`

Here is the Java code to generate the JWT for when the secret is not base64 encoded.

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
public class JWTEncodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String secretkey="qwertypassword";

            //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
            String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject("admin")
                .setAudience("Solr")
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,secretkey.getBytes()).compact();

            System.out.println("jwtToken=");
            System.out.println(jwtToken);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing in this Java code to generate the JWT with the secret base64 encoded to produce the JWT value of

`eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.SWCJDd6B_m7xr_puQH-wgbxvXyJYXH9lTpldOU0eQKc`

Comment: What is the problem you have? Can't you just base64 encode your `secretkey`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/encoding-as-base64-in-java for how you use base64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of `secret base64 encoded` on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) is actually, that it treats the secret you provide as `base64`encoded and therefore first decodes it, before it is actually used. The point is not to create anything different, but just to decode the secret when it is encoded.

The secret you used is, in it's clear, **not encoded** form:

> qwertypassword

When you base64 encode it, eg. with the help of https://www.base64encode.org/, you get this as **base64 encoded** value:

> cXdlcnR5cGFzc3dvcmQ=

On [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) you can use both forms:

- the first, **not encoded** one with the `base64 encoded secret` 
  **checkbox unchecked**

  or
- the second, **base64 encoded** one with the **checkbox checked**.

In both cases you would get the same result.

For your java code it would require an extra step to decode the encoded secret, before using it to sign:

```
import java.util.Base64;

String base64EncodedSecret = "cXdlcnR5cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
byte[] decodedSecret = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedSecret);
```

and then, when you create the JWT, you use the decoded secret:

```
.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, decodedSecret)
```

But that's only necessary, if you get the secret for some reason in encoded form.

Comment: This doesn't work the JWT token at

https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIiLCJleHAiOjE1NjkwMzY5NTl9.CTL0HdcqBtq5fS2Uf2M3UqIxmInAE24dzQ2ybIsOoO4

when the secret base64 endcoded is checked produces the JWT token

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIiLCJleHAiOjE1NjkwMzY5NTl9.CTL0HdcqBtq5fS2Uf2M3UqIxmInAE24dzQ2ybIsOoO4

The Java code produces
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.5T7L_L1MPfQ_5FjKGa1fTPqrzwK4bNSM812nW6oyjb8

Comment: If you really want to treat `qwertypassword` as base64 encoded value, then just replace the contents of the `base64encodedSecret`variable with `quertypassword`. But in my answer I tried to explain how to use base64 encoding. My focus was not to reproduce the exact result of treating your secret as base64 encoded, because it is not really a base 64 encoded value. It doesn't make sense to just take a random string and say it is base64 encoded. Therefore I showed you how your random secret would look like in base64 encoded form. Please read my answer again carefully.

Comment: Thanks this did work

            String secretkey="qwertypassword";
            byte[] decodedSecret = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretkey);

           ...
           .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,decodedSecret).compact();

Produces the JWT key I was expecting.

Comment: Better to call `.signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(decodedSecret))`

Comment: I miss understood the option, secret base64 encoded. When it's checked, the value you entered in that box will be base64 decoded. I thought the other way around. So glad to find the discussion here, and up voted already.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the solution that worked for me, based on JPS feedback

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;    
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import java.util.Base64;


public class JWT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String secretkey="qwertypassword";
            byte[] decodedSecret = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretkey);

            //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
            String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject("admin")
                .setAudience("Solr")
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,decodedSecret).compact();

            System.out.println("jwtToken=");
            System.out.println(jwtToken);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The value of the JWT key is the expected

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.SWCJDd6B_m7xr_puQH-wgbxvXyJYXH9lTpldOU0eQKc

That the site 
https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1ZCI6IlNvbHIifQ.5T7L_L1MPfQ_5FjKGa1fTPqrzwK4bNSM812nW6oyjb8

produces.