# Encript static resource ResourceHandlerRegistry in spring boot

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
final String PRODUCT_IMAGES_LOCATIONS = String.format("file:///%s/", SystemParams.PRODUCT_IMAGE_FOLDER);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/product/image/**").addResourceLocations(PRODUCT_IMAGES_LOCATIONS)
                .setCachePeriod(0);
```

It creates a url for the a tag of the form
http://localhost:9090/pocola/product/image/1/fc29a4cb6dc14125a65e063ad84ff8d6.jpg

So i want encript url for href of tag a .
Please help me . Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you want to encrypt it? What are you expecting?

Comment: I want encrypt it to base64 string, namely the following : http://localhost:9090/pocola/product/image/ADdada21dadad123afada==

Comment: @phuclv3 That is not encrypting. If you want to use base64 there are several libraries you can choose from, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/encoding-as-base64-in-java