# pass shell script as custom_data in Azure using java sdk

Tags: java, linux, azure, spring-boot

I am creating a linux vm using a custom image from an shared image gallery using java sdk.

```
virtualMachine = azure.virtualMachines()
                        .define(linuxVMName)
                        .withRegion(location)
                        .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
                        .withExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterface)
                        .withLinuxCustomImage(customImageUrl)
                        .withRootUsername(username)
                        .withRootPassword(password)
                        .withCustomData(custDatastring)
                        .withComputerName(linuxVMName)
                        .withExistingStorageAccount(storageAccount)
                        .withSize(vmSize())
                        .create();
```

How to pass a linux shell script here in the withCustomData part. I know the input for the method is Base64 encoded string.
I am trying to pass an example script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is some text" > randomtext.txt
```

p.s: I can't create a file for the script here, i have to pass the above command directly to the api. That is my requirement.

How should i handle the customdata part here. Any help is appreciated.

vm create request osprofile json

```
"osProfile":{"computerName":"xxxx","adminUsername":"xxx","adminPassword":"xxx","customData":"IyEvYmluL2Jhc2gKIGVjaG8gIlRoaXMgaXMgc29tZSB0ZXh0IiA+IHJhbmRvbXRleHQudHh0","linuxConfiguration":{"disablePasswordAuthentication":false}}
```

response os profile

```
"osProfile": {
      "computerName": "xxxx",
      "adminUsername": "xxxx",
      "linuxConfiguration": {
        "disablePasswordAuthentication": false,
        "provisionVMAgent": true
      },
      "secrets": [],
      "allowExtensionOperations": true,
      "requireGuestProvisionSignal": true
    }
```

The image i use here is a custom linux image built on centos 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Java 8 Basic Base64](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode#1-java-8-basic-base64), you could use `java.util.Base64`. First, import it as you normally do:

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

then

```
String originalInput = "#!/bin/bash\n echo \"This is some text\" > randomtext.txt";
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalInput.getBytes());
```

Then use it like this,

```
virtualMachine = azure.virtualMachines()
                        .define(linuxVMName)
                        .withRegion(location)
                        .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
                        .withExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterface)
                        .withLinuxCustomImage(customImageUrl)
                        .withRootUsername(username)
                        .withRootPassword(password)
                        .withCustomData(encodedString)
                        .withComputerName(linuxVMName)
                        .withExistingStorageAccount(storageAccount)
                        .withSize(vmSize())
                        .create();
```

I tried it.

[image]

On Linux, this data is passed to the VM via the `ovf-env.xml` file, which is copied to the `/var/lib/waagent` directory during provisioning.  Newer versions of the Microsoft Azure Linux Agent will also copy the base64-encoded data to `/var/lib/waagent/CustomData` as well for convenience.

I can find the custom data in the path `/var/lib/waagent/ovf-env.xml` on My Ubuntu16.04LTS.

[image]

For more examples, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/encoding-as-base64-in-java) and [Custom Data and Cloud-Init on Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-data-and-cloud-init-on-windows-azure/).

Comment: I tried as you said, in my request os profile i can see the custom data encoded string,
but in my response for vm creation there is no customdata part.
i have updated the json req and resp in the question part

Comment: Why do you think it will exist on the response, I check the [get API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#linuxconfiguration). It did not display the custom data even I use the standard Azure Ubuntu image and I also create another VM with `az vm create..` Both are the same.  The custom data did not display in the response.

Comment: In fact, a provisioning agent processes that, such as the Linux Agent and cloud-init. The provisioning agents installed on the VMs handle interfacing with the platform and placing it on the file system. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/custom-data#linux) for more details.

Comment: I am storing the script data in a blob field in database, guess I have made a mistake in storing the script properly. Thanks for the help. much appreciated